# Saving a JSON string to a file is not working

Tags: json, react-native

I am retrieving a JSON string from a PHP file as follows:

```
async fetchAvailableSets(){
    try {
        let response = await fetch('http://example.com/getdata.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }

        })
        let responseJson = await response.json()
        .then((responseData) => {

            console.log(responseData) /* This displays the JSON text */


            RNFS.writeFile(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + 'info.json', responseData)
            .then(() => {
                RNFS.readFile(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + 'info.json')
                .then((contents) => {
                    console.log(contents)   /* Nothing is displayed */
                })
            })
        })
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

If I change the writeFile line to:

```
RNFS.writeFile(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + 'info.json', responseData.toString())
```

then all I get written to the file is "[object Object]". It seems like this is a string rather than a legitimate object.

I feel that it should not need to convert it to a string as it is already a string. Also, it's a bit confusing as to why converting it to a string makes it an object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it give you the same thing if you do `JSON.stringify(responseData)`?

Comment: @MattAft Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.stringify(responseData);
```

would be more appropriate;